# TinyMCE | What data to determine a new line entered?

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

I am able to get tinymce to console log a statement upon adding a new blank line. Here is my code:

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const range = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getRng(true);
    const text = range.startContainer.textContent;

    if ((text.substring(range.startOffset - 1, range.startOffset) == '') &&
        (text.substring(range.startOffset, range.startOffset + 1) == '')) {
          console.log('enter hit');
    }
}
```

However I am having difficulty getting code to fire when a new line is entered due to text overflow. Such as in the below screen shot.

[image]

> What tinymce data can I use to determine that a new line was entered on the keypress event?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how to capture a `keypress` event from within TinyMCE.  The example logs the entire event - the console can be used to see all the useful data in the event.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/0rgaab/1

Comment: I have successfully implemented the keypress event. However I am not sure what tinymce data to use to determine that a new line was entered. Any ideas?

Comment: Define what you want when you say "a new line was entered".  Pressing 
 `Enter` or `Shift`+`Enter` would lead to a new root block or `<br />` which are effectively new lines.

Comment: What I mean is when the cursor position moves to down on the y-axis. For examples if a typed string exceeds the width of the editor, the rest of the string is will be typed on the next line (see screenshot)

Comment: So that is not a "new line" that is just the text wrapping based on the container size and how HTML/CSS works.  There are no events that the editor would fire for such things.